# Ignore escape sequences in ASCII art

Tags: java, escaping, backslash, ascii-art

For my command-line-interfaces it's often nice to have a little ASCII art in the beginning, but those often contain many backslashes.

For example:

```java
System.out.println("  _____ _______       _____ _  __ ");
System.out.println(" / ____|__   __|/\   / ____| |/ / ");
System.out.println("| (___    | |  /  \ | |    | ' /  ");
System.out.println(" \___ \   | | / /\ \| |    |  <   ");
System.out.println(" ____) |  | |/ ____ \ |____| . \  ");
System.out.println("|_____/   |_/_/    \_\_____|_|\_\ ");
```

But since every `\` needs to be a `\\` this often looks very ugly in code and it's very hard to find/fix an error in the 'font'. Is there a way to tell Java NOT to use escape sequences?

Comment: "\\" is the only way to go.  If you *really* don't want the double- backquotes, you can always 1) create a static String[] array with each line of text, 2) substitute some "acceptable" marker character for your slash, 3) println() the array in a loop, and 4) String.replace() the marker character with "\\".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Java doesn't have anything like the "verbatim string literals" of C#. If you want to do ASCII art, consider putting it into a text file instead and loading that from the code.

Answer (score 2):

read that "image" from file, that file can be in your jar library :)

Answer (score 2):

Hate to gravedig this thread, but for anyone else out there looking for this..
Try using unicode!

For example:
\u0092 = "\"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, dude.  No such animal exists.